# Can a replicant be Mongo 3.0 with Primary and Arbiter at 2.6?

Tags: mongodb

I have a replica set: Primary, Secondary and Arbiter. They are all at version 2.6.
Authorization via keyfile.
I'm planing to add new Secondary member with MongoDB 3.0 & wired tiger storage engine. And when it will be synced, replace Primary (2.6) with this new instance (3.0).

Will it work? Maybe someone did that before?

Answer (score 1):

Solution1 (Recommened)

You can upgrade all 2.6 instances to 3.0 first, following this document https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/, and then add 3.0 secodary.

it will be convenient for administrating in the future.

Notice You must also upgrade your driver to 3.0.

---

Solution2

Keep 2.6 instances untouched.

Because 2.6 use MONGODB-CR, but 3.0 use SHA-SCRAM-1 to do authenticaiton work, you source config 3.0 to use MONGODB-CR to keep backward compatible, see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.authenticationMechanisms

Comment: I want to avoid possible downtime.